# custom annotation processing

Tags: java, annotations, processor

I need a help on java custom annotations, I know how to create annotations but I do not know how to process that.
I have gone through some information where I saw APT which is `com.sun.mirror.*` and another `javax.annotation.processing.*`, I got confused between two.

Can any one please guide me to process custom annotations and provide useful link.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between the old *apt* (annotation processing tool, in `com.sun.mirror`) and its successor, the *Pluggable Annotation API* (which is a part of *javac* since 1.6). 
The new API used for processing is in `javax.annotation.processing`.

The API used for analysing declaration elements of the source code is the *Mirror API*, its package is in `javax.lang.model`, that API has similarities with the Reflection API.

Many sources will probably talk about apt, but are still valid for the processor tool in javac. Just the packages and the way to run the processing tool have changed.
[Here is a tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to process annotations at/before compile time (i.e. for producing "side files") then use [apt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html).

OTOH if you need to process annotations at runtime then just [use java reflection to get annotation on particular class](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/ObtainingAllAnnotationsgetAnnotations.htm).